# Couchdb Production configuration

Tags: performance, ubuntu, couchdb

I am using couchdb in production environment on a ubuntu 14.0.4 and the server is a dedicated server with 12 core cpu and 32 GB ram. This couchdb server is connected to an application server with multiple node.js applications running in cluster mode.

The site is experiencing a slight delay in responses and couchdb server statistics are strange. Couchdb is only using 1 GB ram and 2 to 3% on just 2 cores. Is there a way where I can make couchdb use more ram and cpu to increase performance.

Comment: Do you use views? If you do, how many design docs you have for your views?

Comment: sorry for a late reply. yes i was able to figure out that the application connected to the database doesnt rely on views and instead is running queries directly on the document repository.